# Linking Latex Tables to Beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

Is there a way to link Latex table titles to Beamer?  If I change the table titles in Latex and I want to include these titles in my Beamer tables, is there a way to have these titles automatically sent into Latex?

Comment: It may help if you try to describe what you are trying to do, or give an example.  I really do not understand what do you mean by linking table titles (in fact, I am not even sure what "table titles" are).

Comment: No idea what is really needed here: too localised.